# Error "resource could not be found" in Silverlight navigation

Tags: c#, silverlight, url, navigation

i have 3 pages home.xaml, usermap.xaml, farm.xaml and for that i am trying to create a navigation system in MainPage.xaml using this

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootGridStyle}">
        <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" Style="{StaticResource ContentBorderStyle}">

            <sdk:Frame   x:Name="MainContent" Source="/Home" Style="{StaticResource ContentFrameStyle}"
                         Navigated="ContentFrame_Navigated" NavigationFailed="ContentFrame_NavigationFailed">
                <sdk:Frame.UriMapper>
                    <uriMapper:UriMapper>
                        <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="" MappedUri="/Views/Home.xaml"/>
                        <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/{pageName}" MappedUri="/Views/{pageName}.xaml"/>
                    </uriMapper:UriMapper>
                </sdk:Frame.UriMapper>
            </sdk:Frame>
        </Border>

        <Grid x:Name="NavigationGrid" Style="{StaticResource NavigationGridStyle}">

            <Border x:Name="BrandingBorder" Style="{StaticResource BrandingBorderStyle}">
                <StackPanel x:Name="BrandingStackPanel" Style="{StaticResource BrandingStackPanelStyle}">

                    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource LogoIcon}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationNameTextBlock" Style="{StaticResource ApplicationNameStyle}" 
                               Text="Jeevan"/>

                </StackPanel>
            </Border>

            <Border x:Name="LinksBorder" Style="{StaticResource LinksBorderStyle}">
                <StackPanel x:Name="LinksStackPanel" Style="{StaticResource LinksStackPanelStyle}">

                    <HyperlinkButton x:Name="Link1" Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" 
                                     NavigateUri="/Home" TargetName="ContentFrame" Content="Home"/>

                    <Rectangle x:Name="Divider1" Style="{StaticResource DividerStyle}"/>

                    <HyperlinkButton x:Name="Link2" Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" 
                                     NavigateUri="/UserMap" TargetName="ContentFrame" Content="User Map"/>

                    <Rectangle x:Name="Divider3" Style="{StaticResource DividerStyle}"/>

                    <HyperlinkButton x:Name="Link3" Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" 
                                     NavigateUri="/Farm" TargetName="ContentFrame" Content="Farm"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>

        </Grid>

    </Grid>
```

and when i try to run this... it shows Home.xaml page content but when clicking on any of the hyperlinks it shows error...

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /UserMap

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.225
```

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the UriMapper in your code:

```
<uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="" MappedUri="/Views/Home.xaml"/>
<uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/{pageName}" MappedUri="/Views/{pageName}.xaml"/>
```

You will notice that it is looking in "/Views/{pageName}.xaml"

"/Views" is a folder in your solution.

Have you checked to make sure your other pages (eg. UserMap and Farm) are also in that folder? That seems to be your issue - that they are not there.